# Docker throwing ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints whenever I try to build GetTogether

Tags: docker, build, constraints

'Sup fam, I'm trying to build a site using GetTogether and I'm following the instructions herein: https://github.com/GetTogetherComm/GetTogether

Everything has went okay so far; I had to use python3 -m for some of the python commands, but other than that the build went fine.

Then I tried to build the Docker image.

It does not want to build the Docker image.

This is what happens when I try to build the Docker image:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  74.93MB
Step 1/19 : FROM python:3-alpine as builder
 ---> 872c3118ec53
Step 2/19 : WORKDIR /home/python
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 203fb3a9909b
Step 3/19 : RUN apk add --no-cache zlib-dev build-base python-dev jpeg-dev
 ---> Running in 87f4f8436424
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  python-dev (missing):
    required by: world[python-dev]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache zlib-dev build-base python-dev jpeg-dev' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried everything. I tried Googling for these supposed missing packages. I tried bribery. I tried singing gentle lullabies to it and rubbing its back. I even gave it some of my weed. Nothing makes it work. NOTHING.

Please help. For my sanity. For my weed stash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python3-dev instead of python-dev [found here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/issues/496)

Comment: I love you forever now. Thank you <3